# i am getting a nonetype for this

Tags: python, string, nonetype

```
def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            talk('listening')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            command = command.replace('alexa', '')
            talk(command)
    except:
        pass
        
def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if  'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play','')
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
        talk('playing' + song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H %M %p')
        talk('time is' + time)
    elif 'search' in command:
        person = command.replace('search','')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 2)
        talk(info)
        print(info)
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    elif 'google' in command:
        google = command.replace('google','')
        pywhatkit.search(google)
        talk(google)
    else:
        talk('say that again please')
```

i tried to change by specifying that it was a string but i had failed
i am running this and when i am asking if when a str is found in reponse it is telling me the str is a nonetype and i am not sure wether it is like this because of the quotations or because it was specified elsewhere

Comment: Please provide traceback you get.

Comment: `take_command()` doesn't return anything. What is supposed to be assigned to `command`?

Comment: You need `return command` in `take_command()`

Comment: "i am getting a nonetype for this" What does this mean, exactly? Please see [ask] and the [help].

Answer (score 0):

If you run this:

```py
command = take_command()
print(command)
```

*command* have to be *None* because your function (*take_command*) does not return anything, so None is returned by default.

Comment: i have types the command = take_command under defining run_alexa